# Sencha Cmd failed to resolve dependency PARRENTCLASS

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs4.1, sencha-cmd

I'm having a problem with the Sencha Cmd tool; when I try to build my app, I get this error:

```
[DBG] adding implicit dependency for Ext.application call
[DBG] Creating virtual class definition Myapp.app.Application
[DBG] detected application name : Myapp
[DBG] Caching symbol declarations
[DBG] Linking class inheritance graph
[ERR] Failed to resolve dependency PARRENTCLASS for file Myapp.
[ERR] Error executing page compilation Unknown definition for dependency : PARRENTCLASS
```

Does anyone know what this means? The `PARRENTCLASS` dependency and the filename `Myapp` look strange, as I don't even have that file.

My `app.js`:

```
// DO NOT DELETE - this directive is required for Sencha Cmd packages to work. 
//@require @packageOverrides
Ext.application({
    name: 'Myapp',
    appFolder: 'app',
    autoCreateViewport: true,
    controllers: ["BreadCrumbs", "Content", "Lang", "Login", "Ping", "SidebarMenu", "TopMenu"],
    requires: ['Myapp.singleton.Context', 'Myapp.singleton.StoreRefresh', 'Myapp.singleton.Utils', 'Myapp.singleton.MsgBox']
});
```

What is causing this error?

Comment: Looks like you don't have your app or structure configured right.  You will need to post more code.  Maybe start with your app.js file.  Also what version of cmd?

Comment: Added my app.js, version of cmd is v4.0.0.126, before i tried it on v3.1.2.342 with same result.